# I am not getting the mean of a set when I calculate the mean of its subsets means

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am stucked with some python code because I am not getting the mean of my set when I calculate the mean of the means of its subsets.

```
#First I define my mean fucntion:
def mean_f(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

#Then I calculate the mean of my whole dataset directly
myset=[28, 36,76,23,34,856,77,90,22,34,12,80,34, 106, 39]
mean_f(myset)
103.13333333333334

#Finally, I calculate the mean of my dataset using the means of its subsets:
subset1=[28,36,76]
subset2=[23,34,856,77,90]
subset3=[22,34]
subset4=[12,80,34,106,39]

mean_f([mean_f(subset1), mean_f(subset2), mean_f(subset3), mean_f(subset4)])
86.21666666666667
```

Do you know why am I not getting the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply average means of subsets *if these subsets have different numbers of elements*.

As a simple example, suppose one subset consists of the smallest element alone, and the other subset contains all other elements. If you then average these subsets' means, the smallest element will get the same weight as all other elements *together*.

The solution is to take a *weighted* average of the subset means, where each subset's mean gets a weight that is proportional to the number of elements in the subset.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it'd be the same if sets had equal sizes.